# Should reused exceptions types be favored over single use ones?

Tags: java, exceptions, class-design

Let's say I have `Door`s that are managed by a `DoorService`. The `DoorService` is in charge of opening, closing and locking the doors that are stored on the database.

```
public interface DoorService
{
    void open(Door door) throws DoorLockedException, DoorAlreadyOpenedException;

    void close(Door door) throws DoorAlreadyClosedException;

    /**
     * Closes the door if open
     */
    void lock(Door door) throws DoorAlreadyLockedException;
}
```

For the lock method, there's a `DoorAlreadyLockedException` and for the open method there's a `DoorLockedException`. This is an option but there's other options possible:

1) Use `DoorLockedException` for everything, is a bit awkward when catching the exception on a `lock()` call

```
try
{
    doorService.lock(myDoor);
}
catch(DoorLockedException ex) // door ALREADY locked
{
    //error handling...
}
```

2) Have the 2 exceptions types `DoorLockedException` and `DoorAlreadyLockedException`

3) Have the 2 exceptions types but let `DoorAlreadyLockedException extends DoorLockedException`

Which is the best solution and why?

Comment: How do you define "best?"  In C# we don't even have checked exceptions.  We believe that this makes our development simpler and more reliable.

Comment: How different are the resolutions to AlreadyLocked and Locked?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I consider exceptions part of the logic of the method. The best solution is the one that is the most explicit and most logical. Unlike in C#, we are promoting explicitation over convenience by forcing the catch of exceptional case and making sure no ones calls a method without having a full understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Then I guess you already know the answer.  The solution you have identified as the best solution is the one with multiple exception types, since it is clearly the most explicit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But at the cost of a similar/duplicated class? I guess I defined "best" with my opinion instead of something more standard. I'd like to know what is the "best java way" of doing it. Also there's 2 options with 2 exception types and I don't know which to pick.

Comment: I'd like to mention that this question was motivated by a disagreement I had with a teamate/coworker. Saying "you know what's best for yourself" isn't very helpful hahaha

Comment: The best way of doing anything in software development is to do that thing that provides the most benefits for the least cost.  In my opinion, multiple exception types do not add enough value here to justify their additional expense, especially if there's only one reason an exception might be thrown.  There is nothing about this that is Java specific, other than the inherent verbosity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What you just said helped me clarify my question's title. I hope it's more straightforward now.

Comment: These methods should simply be returning a status code.  You can inform your users based on the code you get back, and get a performance boost for free (exceptions are expensive, about 1000 to 10000 times more expensive than returning a status code).

Comment: Consider changing the method name lock with bar, block or disable. Lock has a distinct meaning in programming that relates to threading. If you are into that, your mind flips the wrong way reading your code.

Comment: @MartinMaat I'd do that for C#, fortunately it is not.

Comment: [Try to never write a library that throws a vexing exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)

Comment: @Caleth *Vexing exceptions are thrown in a completely non-exceptional circumstance* that's assuming that a user entering "hawahrw" when asking to input a number in a config file or a console is not exceptional. Such validation is out of the control flow of the program as the point of the program isn't to complain about bad inputs but to offer some kind of feature. IMO, handling bad inputs with exceptions is appropriate and removes the noise from the main logic.

Comment: @Winter just as long as you undo all the things preceding the exception

Comment: @Caleth Making a system that starts making changes without full information and then undoes it when it encounters an error wouldn't be a good idea IMO. All the information should be gathered and validated before any use.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "exceptions are expensive, about 1000 to 10000 times more expensive than returning a status code"  I've done some analysis on this in Java and the cost of exceptions is often way over-stated.  They 'can' be expensive if you have very deep stacks.  IIRC, I had to bump up the max stack size significantly to be able to create stacks large enough to make exceptions slow enough to worry about.  Even stack pigs like Spring don't do that.  As long as you aren't throwing and catching in tight loops, it's premature optimization to avoid exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, but even still I think this is a bad example as I would consider attempting to lock a locked door unexceptional.  It’s simply not an error; the door just remains locked.  I feel like regardless of the system performance impacts, unnecessary exception handling has a negative impact on developer performance and code maintenance.

Comment: @Paul That depends on how the service is used, which you can't deduce from this example. *unnecessary exception handling has a negative impact on developer performance and code maintenance* in Java we have `throws` so you write the whole thing on the first time and everything gets well handled on the first time. Having to search the doc for a magic value has a bigger impact on developper performance and motivation. But anyway, the Magic value vs Exception debate already happened on another question. This question is about naming a single exception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know people make a big deal out of using exceptions for flow control but that isn't the biggest problem here. I see a huge [command query separation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) violation. But even that's not the worst.

No, the worst is right here:

```
/**
 * Closes the door if open
 */
```

Why the hell does everything else blow up if your assumption about the doors state is wrong but `lock()` just fixes it for you? Forget that this makes it impossible to lock the door open, which is absolutely possible and occasionally useful. No the problem here is you've mixed two different philosophies for dealing with incorrect assumptions. That's confusing. Don't do that. Not at the same level of abstraction with the same naming style. Ow! Take one of those ideas outside. The door service methods should all work the same way.

As for the Command Query Separation violation I shouldn't have to try to close a door to find out if it's closed or open. I should be able to just ask. The door service doesn't provide a way to do that without possibly changing the state of the door. That makes this so much worse then commands that also happen to return values (a common misunderstanding of what CQS is about). Here, state changing commands are the only way to do queries! Ow!

As for exceptions being more expensive than status codes, that's optimization talk. Fast enough is fast enough. No the real problem is that humans don't expect exceptions for typical cases. You can argue over what's typical all you like. For me the big question is how readable you're making the using code.

```
ensureClosed(DoorService service, Door door){
  // Need door closed and unlocked. No idea of its state. What to do?
  try {
    service.open(door)
    service.close(door)
  } 
  catch( DoorLockedException e ){
    //Have no way to unlock the door so give up and die
    log(e);
    throw new NoOneGaveMeAKeyException(e);      
  }
  catch( DoorAlreadyOpenedException e ){
    try { 
      service.close(door);
    }
    catch( DoorAlreadyClosedException e ){
      //Some multithreaded goof has been messing with our door.
      //Oh well, this is what we wanted anyway.
      //Hope they didn't lock it.
    }
  }
}
```

Please don't make me write code like this. Please give us `isLocked()` and `isClosed()` methods. With those I can write my own `ensureClosed()` and `ensureUnlocked()` methods that are easy to read. Ones that only throw if their post conditions are violated. I'd rather just find you've already written and tested them of course. Just don't mix them together with the ones that throw when they can't change the state. At the very least give them distinguishing names.

<sub>Whatever you do, please don't call anything `tryClose()`. That's a terrible name.</sub>

As for `DoorLockedException` alone vs also having `DoorAlreadyLockedException` ill say this: it's all about the using code. Please don't design services like this without writing the using code and looking at the mess you're creating. Refactor and redesign until the using code is at least readable. In fact, consider writing the using code first.

```
ensureClosed(DoorService service, Door door){
  if( !service.isClosed(door) ){
    try{
      service.close(door);
    }
    catch( DoorAlreadyClosedException e ){
      //Some multithreaded goof has been messing with our door.
      //Oh well, this is what we wanted anyway.
      //Hope they didn't lock it.
    }
  } else {
    //This is what you wanted, so quietly do nothing. 
    //Why are you even here? Who bothers to write empty else conditions?
  }
}

ensureUnlocked(DoorService service, Door door){
  if( service.islocked(door) ){
    throw new NoOneGaveMeAKeyException(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: The `lock()` method that is calling `close()` was just me being lazy when writing the question, but thanks for making me aware of that! I won't fall for it when writing real code. In my case, the 3 methods are never really called successively. It's just: call one, if there's no exception good, otherwise show a translated dialog and possibly logout (if InvalidTokenException). I have `isLocked()` and `isOpen()` methods and they are used in the control flow of the server but they shouldn't be used as a way to check if an error dialog should be shown, that's a job for an exception.

Comment: For your last point well, yes the using code looks a bit better with `DoorAlreadyLockedException` but it makes twin classes.

Comment: If by twin classes you mean the exceptions themselves let me show you my favorite use of inheritance: `public class DoorAlreadyLockedException inherits DoorLockedException {}`. Define a class in one line just for the sake of giving it a good name. Choose what you inherit from wisely. I much prefer to inherit from as high up as I can, while not being pointlessly redundant, to avoid a long inheritance chain.

Comment: I feel like renaming the `NoOneGaveMeAKey` to `NoOneGaveMeAKeyException` just to be pendantic. Otherwise I agree with the main point which is that before processing, we need to be able to know the state of the object.

Comment: Devil's advocate - just having `isOpen`/`isClosed` isn't good enough. Think about the filesystem. You can check the file does/does not exist, but that can still change by the time you try to read or write it, and an `IOException` will result. Maybe in this context there really is the chance the state is invalid when you open or close the door.

Comment: @TomG exactly; the `isClosed()` and `isLocked()`methods add not much value; you're gonna have to use `close()` and `lock()` anyway to find out if the door could *actually* be locked/closed. This is pretty common. [Race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: @Robll you use `isClosed()` and `isLocked()` as alternatives to changing state to determine state. The alternative to throwing when asked to close a closed door is to quietly do nothing.

Answer (score 8):

Making a distinction between `DoorLockedException` and `DoorAlreadyLockedException` suggests that different exception types are being used for flow control, a practice that is already widely considered an antipattern.

Having multiple exception types for something this benign is gratuitous.  The additional complexity is not outweighed by the additional benefits.

Just use `DoorLockedException` for everything.

Better yet, simply do nothing.  If the door is already locked, then it will still be in the correct state when the `lock()` method completes.  Don't throw exceptions for conditions that are unremarkable.

If you're still uncomfortable with that, then rename your method `ensureDoorLocked()`.

Comment: Please don't overuse the "exceptions for flow control" meme, if the two situations, for whatever reason, warrant dramatically different courses of action to resolve, then having different exceptions makes sense. Not clear from the example if that's the case though.

Comment: @whatsisname: If it's a meme that has no basis in fact, then post your own answer to that effect.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In our case it's not doors but video game levels. The user needs to be warned that his levels was already locked and he is doing something wrong.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Exceptions are used for the "control flow" of the error dialogs and error logging. The main logic application is obviously not run though the catch clauses. I do not think making a distinction between `DoorLockedException` and `DoorAlreadyLockedException` suggests that, it's just about having a much more significative error handler for the `lock()` method at the cost of having an almost duplicated class.

Comment: If you call lock() and the door is locked, you already know that the door was already locked.  You don't need to be told what you already know.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But that forces a call to `isLocked()` or something similar beforehand, forcing the handling of an exceptional case with an if condition instead of a catch clause. Not only that, the service may call a database or even a server that calls a database. Making 2 calls is more data transfered than a single call with an error response.

Comment: What? No.  `DoorLockedException` is semantically identical to `DoorAlreadyLockedException`.  The only reason you want two exceptions is because you think it makes the code more readable.

Comment: I though you were still talking about having a `ensureDoorLocked()`, my bad. Yes it's identical to have one or two types and is all about readability.

Comment: @Winter: it's really hard to make sense out of your example as there isn't enough context. An error code and a decision is a lot faster, and not as much "data transferred" as a thrown exception. If you can use status codes/status objects, you should do it, unless doing so introduces race conditions, and thats where exceptions start to become necessary.

Comment: @whatsisname  Race conditions do not require exceptions, they require locks  :-)

Comment: +1 would go further and just use Exception("door locked"), message for logs only

Comment: @Ewan But then how do you show a translated message to your user or do something different for specific exceptions? Comparing the string? That's dirty

Comment: @whatsisname Performance was never an issue, redundant client-server calls are. I don't get how the status code joke was seriously considered, this is java not C.

Comment: @Winter I dont look at the exception at all. the code checks to see if the door is already locked before attempting to open and presents the user with whatever message

Comment: Or returns an appropriate status code to take action on.  Status codes are not a language-specific feature; it has nothing to do with Java vs C and the suggestion was *not* a joke.

Comment: -9000000 for mentioning status codes!! this isn't 1963!

Comment: @ewan: Oh, ffs.  Call it anything you want; an enumeration, a result, whatever.  It's the right approach.

Comment: @Winter status code jokes, def don't work.

Comment: @ewan gotta go with Harvey on this. My preference would be a Boolean from an `isLocked()` etc. but status codes are alive and well in Java in 2018.

Comment: I'd call it a "result", since in some cases it may have more information than just status, but that does seem more appropriate than an exception, particularly for cases that don't result in an invalid state (trying to close an already closed door, for example).

Answer (score 3):

The subject of this question "Should recycled exceptions types be favored over single use ones?" appears to have been ignored, not only in the answers, but in the details for the questions (the answers were to the details of the question).

I agree with most of the criticism of the code the respondents have offered.

But as an answer to the headline question, I would say that you should strongly prefer re-use of 'recycled exceptions' over 'single use ones'.

In more typical use of exception handling, you have a great DISTANCE in the code between where the exception is detected and thrown, and where the exception is caught and handled. That means using private (modular) types in exception handling generally won't work well. A typical program with exception handling - will have a handful of top-level locations in the code where exceptions are handled. And as those are top-level locations, its hard for them to have detailed knowledge about narrow aspects of particular modules.

Instead, they will likely have a high level handlers for a few high level problems.

The only reason using detailed custom exception classes appears to make sense in your sample, is because (and here I'm parroting the other respondents) - you shouldn't be using exception handling for ordinary control flow.

Comment: "In more typical use of exception handling, you have a great DISTANCE" We aren't analyzing what is typical. We're designing a way for it to work. Many good designs catch their exceptions at the very next level in the call stack and in an extremely limited scope. That shouldn't be dismissed as flow control when all they do is recover from the problem. The best exception designs start by planing how to recover before defining the exceptions. Then the exception names don't have to be about reporting the problem. They're about finding the solution. You can use the msg string to report the problem.

Comment: "We aren't analyzing what is typical. We're designing a way for it to work.", Agreed, that is what you were doing. It is not what I was doing. If you look at the headline, it asked one question. If you look at the body of the message, it asked three different (related) questions. You answered the body questions (to a degree - really- more you criticized the sample code). I answered the headline question.

Comment: BTW, you claim "Many good designs catch their exceptions at the very next level in the call stack and in an extremely limited scope". I'm not sure I would fully disagree with that. But I have to say, after 40 years of programming, I'm having a hard time coming up with an example to support that claim. I realize its a bit of a spin-off (and I maybe not handling this correctly - new to stackoverflow) - but would you mind offering an example or two where such localized try/catch handling is the best solution? It is certainly not a typical/common pattern.

Comment: An example huh? Let me introduce you to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486082/1493294)

Comment: OK, that's not at all an example of what you claimed. You said "Many good designs catch their exceptions at the very next level in the call stack and in an extremely limited scope". Your example was just translating an API that only produced exceptions on error into one that produced some sentinel value instead.  Maybe this is just a wording difference between the two of us. I wouldn't describe that as a "good design" but a 'localized hack to get around an 
 inconvenient design choice in a tool you are using'.

Comment: And - BTW  - I'm not sure that using sentinel values is any better than using exceptions for such errors. That just makes it even harder to see that example as "good design".

Comment: @LewisPringle: example: opening a file. No, checking the file's status before attempting to open isn't going to cut it, as that introduces a race condition.

Comment: @whatsisname Sorry to be slow slow - but I'm not following your example. I agree that if your file opening API returns an error code, you want a layer of code to map that into exceptions (as in https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/V2.1-Release/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/IO/FileSystem/FileInputStream.cpp#L61). But the reason this works well is because the high level logic to handle failure to open the file is someplace else in the code - way separated from the place that detected the error.

Comment: This example is also one where I do the throw inside a try/catch and rethrow a different exception (with the filename bound into the exception). But I hesitate to call that 'good design'. Its really just a hack to improve the exception defails for the exception being thrown. Most code will just ignore exceptions and use RAAI - in C++ anyhow - to handle any needed cleanups along the way, and a top level error handling to report back what went wrong, and when the operation (that invoked the file open) failed.

Comment: @LewisPringle: I'm not talking about mapping codes to exceptions, but that some operations you just have to go for it, you can't test then do it. The result is where you see small try/catch blocks where stuff is thrown and caught right away.

Comment: The earlier quote I questioned (didn't say was wrong, just doubted) "Many good designs catch their exceptions at the very next level in the call stack and in an extremely limited scope". I continue to think this is much too strong a claim, and misleading. I would AGREE that there are sometimes times where a localized try/catch is the best tool for the job. But I'd put that at 1% of cases, not something I could call 'a good design'.

Comment: By the way, I think part of the discrepancy maybe my fault. I'm used to programming in C++, which has a VERY powerful feature called RAAI. This is probably - IMHO - the biggest single weakness in Java, and I now note (re-reading) this was marked as a Java question. RAAI makes use of try/catch MUCH MUCH less prevalent in C++ than in Java. Even then, I think the 'catch their exceptions' part would be largely wrong for Java - as you would use try/finally - not try/.catch (to mimic RAAI usage in C++).

Comment: "some operations you just have to go for it, you can't test then do it" - while this is true, at least in C++, its nearly always possible (and preferable) to do that without exceptions. In C++, the methodology is to use try_... methods (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock). And same with the fileIO case you mentioned (you open and maybe get back -1, and or maybe get back valid file descriptor).

Comment: One thing you could argue is BETTER about the runtime library support in java (versus C++) is that most of these operations (like open a file) directly result in an exception. But what makes that a better approach is that you almost always want to deal with that failure elsewhere in the code. That's the REASON for the Java runtime library design choice (they could have returned null pointers analogous to what C++ does). They chose to throw exceptions because they deemed the local handling case RARE and UNIMPORTANT. For local handling, it would have been better to return an error code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the original question, rather than criticising the example.

Simply put, if you expect that the client might need to react differently for each case, it warrants a new exception type.

If you decide to use multiple exception types and you nevertheless expect that the client might in some cases want to create a common catch clause for them, you should probably create an abstract superclass that they both extend.

Answer (score 0):

An unexplored alternative. You may be modelling the wrong thing with your classes, what if you had these instead?

```
public interface OpenDoor
{
    public ClosedDoor close();
    public LockedDoor lock();
}

public interface ClosedDoor
{
    public OpenDoor open();
    public LockedDoor lock();
}

public interface LockedDoor
{
    // ? unlock? open?
}
```

Now it's impossible to attempt anything that is an error. You don't need any exceptions.

Comment: But in most applications you can't keep the reference to those objects, as the database can be changed anytime. Good creative effort though

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudocode but I think you will get what I mean:

```
public interface DoorService
{
    // ensures the door is open, uses key if locked, returns false if lock without a key or key does not fit
    bool Open(Door door, optional Key key) throws DoorStuckException, HouseOnFireException;

    // closes the door if open. already closed doors stay closed. Locked status does not change.
    void Close(Door door) throws throws DoorStuckException, HouseOnFireException;

    // closes the door if open and locks it
    void CloseAndLock(Door door, Key key) throws DoorStuckException, HouseOnFireException;
}
```

Yes, exception type reuse makes sense, *if you use exceptions for truly exceptional things*. Because truly exceptional things are mostly cross-cutting concerns. You were using Exceptions basically for control flows and that leads to those problems.

Comment: But those exception types are really undescriptives. What does it even mean to have a door "stuck" when you can only open, close or lock a door?

Comment: This is just swallowing the exceptions and does nothing with them. This is not appropriate in a context where you wan't to know what's going on. This feels like the C# way to do of my Java example. There's a reason why I'm working with Java.

Comment: Well, that it's stuck. It cannot move. So you cannot open it and you cannot close it. It's not a logical state you need to fix by calling another method, it's an *exceptional* state, that you cannot solve through the door service.

Comment: And it's not swallowing *anything*, it's not producing an exception for a non-exceptional program state. If my wife ask me to please close the balcony door and I get up and find out it's already closed, I don't run around and scream and panic. I just go back and say "it's closed now".

Comment: Exactly, with checked exceptions, the exception can't get back to the start of the program is has to be catched by the caller. On the call you just ignore the exception or log a warning and you are good. Also what you call "exceptional exceptions" are just RuntimeExceptions. `DoorStuckException` and `HouseOnFireException` should not be checked, they aren't meant to be catched on all calls.

Comment: I say it's swallowing them because it makes it so your wife can't ask you to "close the balcony door if open and tell me if it was already closed". She might want to know if a random dude came and close the balcony door. Especially if "your wife" is a user that wants all information about what's going on with the application. Assuming "nothing" is always the right thing to do when a door is already closed is wrong.

Comment: In an environment like your house yeah you don't care much if a door that was supposed to be open is closed or vice versa. You just do what's most logical in your situation. But in more controlled environment, it can be a sign of a catastrophic failure leading to data de-synchronization. In science it would most likely lead to a stop of the current operations and invalidation of any received data.

Comment: I guess whether you catch HouseOnFireException depends largely on whether there is a FireBrigadeService in your app that could handle it. I'm just saying that Exceptions are not return values. If you want to transport back status, use logging or results to do that. What is left is the exceptional stuff and that indeed can simply be reused because it's most likely the same (if a door is locked or already locked really does not matter if it's an *exceptional* condition. You'd not implement a HouseStillOnFireException, the first one is enough to signal all possible scenarios).